# In a C# Console Application, how do you use \n in a table?

Tags: c#, variables, console

Beginner C# question here.

I've got a console app with a table of three columns and ready-to-go variables and I'm writing the output.

The table format, in case it's helpful:

```
const string table = "{0,-25}{1,-4}{2,-15:f2}";
```

\n works fine if the WriteLine is just plain text in quotation marks, such as

```
Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------\n");
```

But I'm lost as to where I put the /n in the table formatted WriteLine, where the final column contains a variable. Example:

```
Console.WriteLine(table, "Total cost of paint", ":", paintTotalWithVAT);
```

I vaguely remember another way of adding the variable - as an aside, the {0} method of place-holding the variable and then declaring it at the end of the brackets seems to not work within the table format - but I'd greatly appreciate some help on this. Ideally I want to have a currency symbol before my variable output (in decimal format) so that would impact the format I need

It's getting a little messy filling my output with a load of empty WriteLines..!

Comment: Not sure if I'm misunderstanding you, but WriteLine will put the \n on the end of the line for you. If you add your own, you'll get blank lines.

Comment: I have no idea of what your actual question is here. If you want content to appear in a separate line, you use another `Console.WriteLine` - that's specifically what it does (write a line of text, followed by a `\n`). So you `WriteLine` the first line, and then `WriteLine` the second line.

Comment: Sorry, what I want to do was add an empty line in the output without taking a hammer to the problem and typing out

    Console.WriteLine();

every time I don't want an output like to be displayed directly under the previous line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you trying to add a new line at the end? just concatenate a new string at the end

```
Console.WriteLine(table, "Total cost of paint", ":", paintTotalWithVAT, "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it inside your `table` string:

```
const string table = "{0,-25}{1,-4}{2,-15:f2}\n";
```

Or if that isn't feasible for some reason you can concatanate it to the string at the WriteLine:

```
Console.WriteLine(table+"\n", "Total cost of paint", ":", paintTotalWithVAT);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Cheers boss!!